# How to serialize a class (JPanel) and why?

Tags: java, serialization, jpanel

How can I serialize a class (JPanel) and **why** should I?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't even know why you should do it, why do you need to know *how*? Anyway the answer is that you shouldn't'. See the statement in the Javadoc in the preamble to the class (indeed to any Swing class).

Answer (score 1):

Well, one reason would be to save some sort of drawing contained in the JPanel and made by a user. I'm developing a drawing board app as a final project for my advanced Java class, and we're supposed to save whatever we draw to a file, and to be able to load that and recall that instance.

What I'm having a hard time is figuring out the "how" part of serializing these objects, and what should be serialized so that loading the file back loads the saved instance of that object or objects.

I'll continue searching SO for clues...